# Soundcloud Player Widget Trigger Events on Track Change

Tags: javascript, jquery, soundcloud

This question is in regards to the Soundcloud Player Widget. Its playground is found here: https://w.soundcloud.com/player/api_playground.html

My current project goal is to stream soundcloud on top of a flickr stream using Supersized. I've accomplished this before using the custom player found on github, but the widget linked above has better browser compatibility.

Please excuse me, I'm still learning how to code widgets like this. I apologize if my lingo is outdated or very roundabout.

There are two essential functions I'm looking to isolate (in order to code more events in the future) and produce.

What I would like to code is:

FIRST:
When the current track ends, stop playing and do NOT seek the next track. INSTEAD, find a 'NEXT' button that is automatically clicked when current track is FINISHED.

SECOND: 
In this example, I'm using the 'mini' player that comes with Soundcloud Pro and Pro Unlimited. 
When a user clicks the 'previous' button on the mini player, I want to isolate the event in order to add more events (such as, when the previous button on the player is clicked, have the previous slide button in supersized clicked automatically)

I hope I articulated this well enough. Here, I'll try to write the same thing in a smaller set of sentences:

Can someone help me find the event handlers for the 'Current Track Finished' event, the 'Next' seek event, and the 'Previous' seek event in the Soundcloud Widget?

I also would really like if you could give me an example in which those events are used (I'm not used to coding for widgets like this and don't usually know how to trigger them)

Answer (score 1):

Find the events to bind on the widget here: http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget#events

To trigger some code when the track ends:

```
var element = $('SOME_SELECTOR');
var widget; 
SC.oEmbed("https://soundcloud.com/olivier-colot/television-rules-the-nation-daft-punk-remix", {}, element[0]);
SC.whenStreamingReady(function() {});
widget = SC.Widget(element.find('iframe')[0]);
widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.FINISH, function(player) {
  // do something
});
```